# Comparing Message Authentication Codes in Apex

Tags: crypto, blob, encodingutil

I'm trying to incorporate message authentication into an application I'm working on. Ideally, I need to verify that the MAC generated by the requester matches the recomputed MAC on the server side. Normally I would compare each bit in the generated Blob, but I don't think Apex supports that.

Any best practices on this? One thing I'm considering is comparing the MAC's character by character to see if the entire message is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use EncodingUtil.base64Encode on both Blob values and compare them as (case-sensitive) strings.

```
String ourMac = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.generateMac(...));
String theirMac = ...;
Boolean isSame = ourMac != null && ourMac.equals(theirMac);
```

You need to use equals in this case, because "==" is actually case insensitive, which is not our desired behavior.

Comment: I'll give this a shot.